# WPF fixed rows are resizing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new in WPF and I try to creat specific UserControl to display data for a single product. I used **Grid** inside UserControl. So I create 5 columns and 3 rows. I want ot make 4 columns fixed (image, green-clored, blue-colored and column with controls) and last column (orange-colored) to fill all availabel space. Here my XAML and few screenshots:

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,5" Background="#FFDCD9D9" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Source="{Binding ItemThumbnailUrl}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0"  />
    <StackPanel  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Background="#FFDA6F6F">
        <Label  BorderThickness="0" Content="dsgsdgsgsgsdgsdg sd " FontSize="13.333" FontWeight="Bold"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF517823" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="70">
        <Label  Content="{Binding ItemPrice}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="9.333" Width="45" />
        <Label Content="грн." HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="9.333" Width="25"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF214299" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="70">
        <Label  Content="{Binding Quantity}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="9.333" Width="45" />
        <Label Content="шт." HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="9.333" Width="25"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF88B91E" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="70">
        <Label  Content="1С" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="9.333" Foreground="#FF8B8888" Width="45"/>
        <Label Content="грн." HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="9.333" Foreground="#FF8B8888" Width="25"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF228CBD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="70">
        <Label  Content="1С" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="9.333" Foreground="#FF8B8888" Width="45"/>
        <Label Content="шт." HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="9.333" Foreground="#FF8B8888" Width="25"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <CheckBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Background="{x:Null}" Content="Редакт." Foreground="#FF444343" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

    <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFE08212" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  />
</Grid>
```

If I have "Title" text (in red-colored cell) less than sum of 3 my fixed columns, everything is OK, but if a text larger I have problems with some paddings between columns (please see pictures)
[image][image]

So how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you try setting the ColumnSpan as 5 for the stackpanel?

Comment: Did you mean red-colred StackPanel ?

Comment: Yes. The one with large text.

Comment: I just tried it but still have same result

Comment: Why do you have label in stackpanels?
You can directly give Grid.ColumnSpan to label itself. Remove stackpanel.
Stackpanel would come in handy if you have two or more controls as children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue in a variety of cases when a Grid is used in a DataTemplate. I removed the `StackPanel` and used a `TextBlock`, then a a `TextBlock` hosted in a separate `Grid`, but all with the same result. I guess something is going wrong when WPF is determining the required size. I have often occurred  this kind of strange behaviour in Grids (when part of an ItemTemplate). If you need a quick workaround then this should do the trick

```
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="80" MaxWidth="80" />
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="70" MaxWidth="70" />
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="70" MaxWidth="70" />
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="70" MaxWidth="70" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```